# How to deal with Spring HttpSecurity authorize request when having cross path?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a rest controller that has such methods:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/blogs")
class DummyController{
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String dummy1(@PathVariable Long id){
        return "dummy1";
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String dummy2(){
        return "dummy2";
    }

    @GetMapping("/vote/status")
    public String dummy3(){
        return "dummy3";
    }
}
```

Here, i want to permit all request to `dummy1` and `dummy2`, but authenticate `dummy3`. As you can see, the exposed paths have cross part. So i configure my Spring security config like:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
    "/register",
                "/login",
                "/logout"
            ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.GET,
                "/blogs/vote/status"
            ).authenticated()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.GET,
                "/blogs",
                "/blogs/{id:\\d+}/**",
                "/blogs/search"
            ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ;
    }
```

Of course, it didn't work, i can request for `dummy1`, `dummy2` and `dummy3` without login.

How should i configure the `HttpSecurity` to achieve my desired authentication strategy?

Answer (score 0):

What I use to achieve this is to define **authorities** (or you can also use **roles**. Something like this:

```java
.antMatchers(
    HttpMethod.GET,
    "/blogs/vote/status"
).hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Or even simpler, in your configuration just define the path you wan't to exclude from the authentication. The last part the **.anyRequest().authenticated()** will handle the other paths:

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
    "/register",
                "/login",
                "/logout"
            ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.GET,
                "/blogs",
                "/blogs/{id:\\d+}/**",
                "/blogs/search"
            ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ;
    }
```

Comment: Nah, i can still access the ```blogs/vote/status``` path without log in.

Comment: Could it be that the path: `"/blogs/{id:\\d+}/**"` is messing with your configuration as it allows `blogs/vote/status`?. Could you try removing it, just to test?

Comment: If i remove it, then the request for ```blogs/{id}``` is authenticated, which is not want i want.